# Is it possible to write a T-SQL query for "Get largest 2" that has O(n) run-time complexity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, query-optimization

Obviously it is possible to find the largest 2 elements in a collection in O(n) time complexity. I wondering if this can be done in SQL Server or if any query that has an `ORDER BY` will always run in at least O(n)*log(n) time.

Answer (score 2):

"if any query . . . has an `ORDER BY` will always run in O(n logn) time."

False.  That is not "obvious" at all.  The following query:

```
select top (2) t.*
from t
order by t.size desc;
```

Will run in O(1) time (I think) with a clustered index on `t(size)` and in O(log n) time with a b-tree index.  For normal data sizes, O(log n) is pretty close to constant time -- just put in a constant of 20 or so.

Comment: at query time this is correct, however you have pre-sorted the list by building an index, it dependents on what the op wants to count as run time. I can build a O(1) sorting algorithm if I can sort the list before I start.

Comment: @gomory-chvatal . . . And that is how SQL databases work.  As a note, the statement in the question is simply wrong.  `ORDER BY` does not imply super-linear runtime in a SQL query.

Comment: Agreed, its just worth noting because you cant get such performance on arbitrary columns without creating an index before use. Depending on the frequency of when this is needed and how often the column changes this may not always be acceptable.